# Как происходит выделение памяти для ссылочного типа?

Tags: c++, c

Оговорюсь сразу, это авр атмел, он же обдурино.

Допустим я напишу `Uint8_t *address;`. Потом где нибудь в коде задам массив `Byte addr[] = {1, 3, 56, 78};`. Дальше сделаю страшную вещь `address = addr;`. Компилятор это съедает видимо потому что размер `addr` известен, но что если сделать так: `Uint8_t *adr = address;`? Компилируется, но что будет при работе, утечка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни в одном приведенном примере не происходит выделения памяти. Когда вы пишите: `address = addr;` - вы просто присваиваете указателю `address` адрес массива `addr`. Поэтому при разыменовывании этого указателя вы получите значения, которые хранятся в массиве `addr`. Так при `*address` или `address [0]` вы получите первый элемент массива, равный `1`. И даже если вы внесете изменения типа `addr [0] = 2;`, то и `address [0]` выведен измененное значение.

А строкой `Uint8_t *adr = address;` вы создаёте ещё один указатель, который аналогичен по своей сути `addr`.

Насчёт утечки — нет, её не будет. Указатели не владеют объектом, на который указывают. Более того, вы сами должны гарантировать, что указываемый объект переживёт все указатели на него (иначе образуется висячая ссылка).

Comment: Во втором абзаце у вас ошибка. Вопрошающий объявляет новый указатель с новым именем (`Uint8_t *adr ...` — обратите внимание на отсутствие второй `d`).

Comment: У меня два кб рам, как указатель может быть 8 байт?

Comment: Ага, верно, не заметил - слишком похожи

Comment: Чаще всего (но не всегда) адрес явялется 8-байтным числом

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, удалил пример кода - вопрошающий не работает с кучей.

Comment: @DowJhob, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @DowJhob, размер указателя зависит от архитектуры (4 байта на x86-32, 8 байт на x86-64).

Comment: А если переменная address четыре байта? То что бы компилятор корректно посчитал оставшуюся память нужно писать uint32_t *addr; ?

Comment: @DowJhob, да. Чтобы узнать количество байт в указателе, можете использовать `sizeof(Uint8_t *)` (раз адрес указателя на именно этот тип вы хотите узнать).

Comment: не, не то,     `uint8_t bytes[4]; uint8_t* raw_address() { return bytes; };` как компилятор узнает сколько байт резервировать?

Comment: или исходить нужно из первичного объявления переменной, а уж на что там потом указывает указатель компилятор разберется?

Comment: или  так  `uint8 * addr; uint8 *address = 0x5656;` пускай по адресу 5656 находится число 0x25. Далее `addr = address; addr = 0x20;`  что будет по адресу 5656?

Comment: 0x25, как и было, так как вы поменяли адрес на который ссылается указатель, а не значение, которое хранится по этому адресу.

Answer (score 1):

> Дальше сделаю страшную вещь `address = addr;`. Компилятор это съедает видимо потому что размер `addr` известен

Тут написана какая-то ерунда. Никакой роли "размер `addr`" и его "известность" (или "неизвестнсть") тут не играет вообще. Указатель `address` просто ставится на начало массива `addr`.

> но что если сделать так: `int8_t *adr = address;`

Ничего не происходит. Просто значение указателя `address` копируется в указатель `adr`.

> Компилируется, но что будет при работе, утечка?

Никаких предпосылок для утечек тут не видно.

Comment: Что у эмаллок под капотом? Она сама будет следить за выделенным куском?

Comment: @DowJhob, какой ещё `malloc()`? Сама переменная хранится либо в стеке (если объявлена в функции), либо сегменте данных программы (если объявлена как глобальная переменная). Указателю же абсолютно без разницы, куда указывать.

Comment: Тогда зачем эмаллок? В случае ОС да, память нужно получить у ОС, а тут я сам себе хозяин, нет?

Comment: @Dow Jhob : Какой еще "эмаллок"? Где вообще объявлен ваш массив? И какое вообще отношение эти указатели имеют к вашему "эмаллок"?

Comment: Выше в комментах мне предлагали изучить эмаллок, зачем не знаю

Comment: @Dow Jhob: Я не знаю, что такое "эмаллок" и никогда о таком не слышал.

Comment: Я не использую эмаллок, я в перегруженные функции по ссылке передаю четыре байта, компилятор на выходе говорит сколько осталось рам, я хочу знать что он точно подсчитывает все на что указывает указатель

Comment: Мне с телефона проще писатьэмаллок чем переключаться на malloc,

Comment: Проще вообще ничего не делать!

Comment: Хорошо, так и поступлю.